# printf("%f") or printf("%lf") for doubles in c?

Tags: c, double

My professor said that when you do scanf doubles are represented with %lf but in printf it's %f (which is for floats.)
This is odd because he said that in his coding class we never use floats, only doubles. He didn't explain why.

I wrote a simple program that prints a double. I used printf with either %lf and %f. The result was the same.

What's the difference?

Comment: `printf` automatically promotes `float` to `double`: you cannot display a `float` with it. `l` has no uses with `f` (with `printf` a least) so it is most likely being ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all "vararg" function (functions whose declarations contains `...`, like for example `printf` and `scanf`) smaller types will be automatically promoted or converted to larger types. For example `short` will be promoted to `int`, and `float` will be promoted to `double`.

That means for `printf` the format `%f` and `%lf` are identical, since the argument will be a `double`.

But for `scanf` you don't pass values that will be promoted or converted, instead you pass *pointers*, for which no conversion will be made. And a pointer to `float` (i.e. `float *`) is very different from a pointer to `double` (i.e. `double *`). So for `scanf` there is a difference between `%f` and `%lf`.